# How can I calculate the bearing/ heading between two GeoPoints ? (lat/lng))

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the logic, I get some latitude and longitude points from the server, I them compare the last received point with the points I receive next and use a function to get the bearing/heading between these points,
In order to do so i need to have 4 double variables of those points, `bearingLat` and `bearingLon` will hold the last point while the `driverLat` and `driverLon` hold the newer points. now i use the method `Geolocator.bearingBetween( driverLat!, driverLon!, bearingLat, bearingLon);` to get the bearing, the problem is driverLat will equal bearingLat while driverlon will equal bearing lon , when I print out it gives a result like this `heading 27.77351058, 85.36021874, 27.77351058, 85.36021874,`

My objective is to get

```
 bearingBetween(
  double startLatitude,
  double startLongitude,
  double endLatitude,
  double endLongitude,
)
```

the class

```
class UpdateDrivers {
  MapController osmController;
  bool removeDriverIcon;
  String? removeDriverKey;
  double? driverLon;
  String? driverKey;
  double? driverLat;
  double bearingLat = 0;
  double bearingLon = 0;
  static const double twoPi = 2 * pi;

  //double twoPi = 2 * pi;

  UpdateDrivers({
    required this.osmController,
    required this.removeDriverIcon,
    this.removeDriverKey,
  });

  void updateAvailableDriversOnMap() async {
    if (removeDriverIcon) {
      //removes the car when the driver goes offline
      await osmController.setStaticPosition([], removeDriverKey!);
      removeDriverIcon = false;
      removeDriverKey = null;
    } else {
      if (GeoFireAssistant.nearByAvailableDriversList.length > 0)
        for (NearByAvailableDrivers driver
            in GeoFireAssistant.nearByAvailableDriversList) {
          driverKey = driver.key!;

          driverLat = driver.latitude!;
          driverLon = driver.longitude!;
          double z = Geolocator.bearingBetween(
              driverLat!, driverLon!, bearingLat, bearingLon);
          print("heading $z");
          
          bearingLat = driverLat!;
          bearingLon = driverLon!;

          if (z.isNegative) {
            z = (twoPi + z);
          }

          print("heading " +
              driverLat.toString() +
              ", " +
              driverLon.toString() +
              ", " +
              bearingLat.toString() +
              ", " +
              bearingLon.toString() +
              ", ");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the log to show I am actually receiving different GeoPoint just not able to handle the function,
below in the 3rd line it should be `heading 27.77351071, 85.36021885, 27.77351097, 85.36021822`

```
I/flutter (13573): heading 27.77351097, 85.36021822, 27.77351097, 85.36021822,
I/flutter (13573): heading 62.148877298990115
I/flutter (13573): heading 27.77351071, 85.36021885, 27.77351071, 85.36021885,
I/flutter (13573): heading 62.14887839428785
I/flutter (13573): heading 27.7735096, 85.36021835, 27.7735096, 85.36021835,
I/flutter (13573): heading 62.1488777544798
I/flutter (13573): heading 27.77351025, 85.36021869, 27.77351025, 85.36021869,
I/flutter (13573): heading 62.14887819652214
I/flutter (13573): heading 27.77350978, 85.36021783, 27.77350978, 85.36021783,
I/flutter (13573): heading 62.14887680439367
I/flutter (13573): heading 27.7735112, 85.36021874, 27.7735112, 85.36021874,
```

Edit- My function is correct, I tried to manually put in Geopoint and calculate the bearing the result is correct, my only issue is bearinglat and bearinglon not taking the last value of driverlat and driverlon

I think its how I instantiated `double bearingLat = 0; double bearingLon = 0;` in the constructor?

Iam calling it from another class in this way

```
 case Geofire.onKeyMoved:
              NearByAvailableDrivers nearByAvailableDrivers =
                  NearByAvailableDrivers(
                      map['key'], map['latitude'], map['longitude']);
              GeoFireAssistant.updateDriverNearByLocation(
                  nearByAvailableDrivers);
              UpdateDrivers updateDrivers = UpdateDrivers(
                osmController: osmController,
                removeDriverIcon: false,
              );
              updateDrivers.updateAvailableDriversOnMap();
              break;
```

Comment: Are you using osmdroid for you map view?

Comment: yes, I am using osm flutter plugin

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in Java.

```
private static double angleFromCoordinate(double lat1, double long1, double lat2,
                                          double long2) {

    double dLon = (long2 - long1);

    double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);

    double brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

    brng = Math.toDegrees(brng);
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360;
    brng = 360 - brng; // count degrees counter-clockwise - remove to make clockwise

    return brng;
```

Comment: My function is not wrong, I tried to manually put in Geopoint and calculate the bearing the result is correct, my only issue is bearinglat and bearinglon not taking the last value of driverlat and driverlon